# Exception when I use a right click on a lot of items

Tags: c#, exception, winapi, clipboard, system.io.file

Hey folks I had this small question I got stuck on while I was trying to learn C# by making a small time program that would copy the text files I have in a right click and send their contents to the clipboard, I know solutions exist for this already but my goal here is to learn about how stuff works. After a certain number of files I seem to be unable to dance around this exception.

(Could also be the number of characters since the number of files that I can take varies depending on their length? Anything past the 140-ish range fails though...)

Thanks in advance for any help.

[Exception I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LZu6.png) (Not able to post pics yet because of forum rank, apologies)

Here is my code

```
using System.Text;

namespace Set_Clip
{
    public class Program
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            var first = true;

            foreach (var arg in args)
            {
                using FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(arg);
                using var sr = new StreamReader(arg);

                if (first)
                    first = false;
                else
                    sb.AppendLine().AppendLine();

                sb.Append(sr.ReadToEnd());
            }
            Thread thread = new(() => Clipboard.SetText(sb.ToString()));
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger to see what file could not be opened.

Comment: I can open any of those files individually but if I select too many of them at once, this problem arises.

Comment: Use a debugger to see what file could not be opened.